# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k X_k$ is Gaussian?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

If $X_k$, $k\in\mathbb N$ are Gaussian random variables and $a_k\in\mathbb R$, is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k X_k$ is a gaussian random variable?
I know that a finite linear combination of gaussian random variables is gaussian, but also the limit?

Comment: Finite linear combination of Gaussian random variables may not be Gaussian. There is a name for the phenomenon where $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are Gaussian random variables such that all their linear combinations are Gaussian: it's called "$(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ having a [multivariate Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)".

Comment: For example, if $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X$ when $|X| \leq 1$, $-X$ when $|X|>1$ then $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian but $X+Y$ is not.

Comment: Are you assuming that the X_k are **i**ndependent? What about **i**dentically **d**istributed? If they are indeed i.i.d. and if the |a_k|'s are positive and bounded below, then the variance of the limit (if any) would be infinite. Which should disqualify it from being gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

Set $a_k=1$ and $E[X] = 1$. Then $E[S_n] = n$ so $E[\lim S_n] = \lim n = \infty.$

Since normal variables have finite variance, $\lim S_n$ is not normal.

But, if, for instance, $a_k = (-1)^k$ or $E[X] =0$ the argument above would not hold. And, in particular, if $a_k = \frac{1}{n}$ CLT gives normality.

Comment: What do you mean by $a_k=1/n$?